# Как в C# стереть предыдущий введенный символ в консоли?

Tags: c#

Пользователь вводит символы по определенному порядку. Необходимо, чтобы если он ошибся, символ стёрся.

Comment: Смотрите методы класса консоли, там можно двигать курсор. Вам надо будет подвинуть его на позицию назад, затереть введенный символ новым (пробелом, например) и подвинуть курсор назад еще раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто, раз вам нужно отслеживать каждый символ можно использовать `Console.ReadKey(true)`. Данная функция считывает клавишу без вывода на экран консоли.

```
// это всё в вашем цикле
char input = Console.ReadKey(true); // получаем ввод

if (условие)
    Console.Write(input);
else
    // если ошибся
```

Можно дополнительно сделать проверку что input это именно символ, а не клавиша